# Failed to run the mfc application when calling a mfc dll with the Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)

Tags: c++, .net, mfc, clr, managed

I need to add Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) to my mfc dll project in order to use managed code in it.
I have do some setting for the all projects according to how to compile MFC and ATL Code By Using /clr from msdn.

I have done a lot of testing. But still failed to run my application although I only add the /clr support to the project without adding any managed code.

See below for details：

The exception, call stack, output information, the difference of output information and dependency dll between using and without using /clr please see [Exception Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmwjX.png)

I can't get any useful information from call stack. I don't know even where to add the break point for debugging. Anyway, it's too later to add the break point at the InitInstance() of the application.

It seems the exception caused by loading dlls according the output information. But I don't know the really reason.

Otherwise I have downloaded a sample solution from msdn see [Sample about Using /clr in MFC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2113). The sample contains a mfc application calling a mfc dll with /clr support. And it works well. When I add my mfc dll(with /clr support) into this sample, it can work well too. I really don't down why it can't work in my solution. I have checked the property setting of my project compare with the sample solution. There seems nothing special.

I do need help, any suggestion?

Comment: About how to compile MFC and ATL Code By Using see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235211.aspx

Comment: The exception on the screenshot -- where it occurred? In what method/function of exe (or dll?) module?

Comment: Hi, Ruslan Garipov. Thank you for your reply. The exception occurred when running my exe in a function of my exe.

Comment: Is exe Windows native or .NET module?

Comment: Getting an AVE when allocating memory is an entirely unremarkable mishap, heap corruption is a very standard bug in C++ code and has nothing to do with /clr.  You'd be well ahead by upgrading from XP, the debug heap in current Windows versions is a terrific tool to diagnose bugs like this.  Turning on the symbol server is highly recommended as well.

Comment: Hi, Hans Passant. Thank you for you reply. I can't upgrade my system now. See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645961/access-violation-when-running-native-c-application-that-uses-a-clr-built-dll?lq=1 About "By systematically removing each library reference and commenting out the calls to that particular library in the application code (unmanaged). The next step is to move these library calls to managed code and pass the information back to the unmanaged side via my bridge DLL." Does it mean I need to check each library reference in my .exe who calls the mfc dll with /clr support.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

I have solved the issue by delaying loaded the dll that cotaines /clr support in the project calling it. See [Set Delay Loaded DLL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMldl.png) for how to delay dlls. It seems the exception caused by the chaotic unmanaged and managed initialization.

"Unmanaged and managed initialization is performed in two separate and distinct stages. Unmanaged initialization takes place first (via DllMain), and managed initialization takes place afterwards, through a .NET-supported construct called a .cctor. " See [Initialization of Mixed Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173266.aspx) for details